# Multiple Get actions with different attribute routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-get, asp.net-web-api-routing

If I design my controller in such a way:

```
public class ItemController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [RoutePrefix("item/dosomething")]
    public void DoSomething(Item item)
    { }

    [HttpGet]
    [RoutePrefix("item/dosomethingnicer")]
    public void DoSomethingNicer(Item item)
    { }

    [HttpGet]
    [RoutePrefix("item/dosomethingelse")]
    public void DoSomethingElse(Item item)
    { }
}
```

Would this work?

Comment: Define "work". Also, `RoutePrefix` should be used on  classes not methods for that you can use `Route` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect a structure more akin to this:

```
[RoutePrefix("item")]
public class ItemController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("dosomething")]
    public void DoSomething(Item item)
    { }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("dosomethingnicer")]
    public void DoSomethingNicer(Item item)
    { }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("dosomethingelse")]
    public void DoSomethingElse(Item item)
    { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Web Api 2 in this way in a lot of Controllers:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/api/{version}/research/export")]
public IHttpActionResult Export(){
     do stuff...
} 

[HttpPost]
[Route("~/api/{version}/research/list")]
public IHttpActionResult List()
{
     do stuff...
}
```

I use full api path description and it works with no problems.