# Multiple GET no good w/ Attribute Routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

This is supposed right:

/api/MyDataController.cs

```
public class MyDataController: ApiController
{
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("GetOne")]  
  public IHttpActionResult GetOne() { }  // works w/o GetTwo

  [HttpGet]
  [Route("GetTwo")]
  public IHttpActionResult GetTwo() { }
}
```

.js

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/MyData/GetOne'})... //works w/o GetTwo
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/MyData/GetTwo'})...
```

Same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435954/web-api-2-multiple-get-actions-with-different-attribute-routing), API version is

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3"
targetFramework="net461" />
```

Both call to **One** and **Two** complained about **GetOne**,

> "Multiple actions were found that match the request: GetOne on type
>   MyWeb.API.MyDataControllerGetOne on type
>   MyWeb.API.MyDataController"

It works if rem-out GetTwo() from Api controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the application is still using convention-based routing.

The reason for the clash is because the default convention-based route template   `api/{controller}/{id}`does not usually provide an action parameter like this `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}`. If you want to get post actions to work via convention-routing when use the template provided before.

If you want to use attribute routing instead then you need to enable attribute routing in the `WebApiConfig.cs` file in order to allow the `Rout` Atrribute to work.

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

You would also need to update your routes to get what you want

```
[RoutePrefix("MyData")]
public class MyDataController: ApiController {

    //GET MyData/GetOne
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetOne")]  
    public IHttpActionResult GetOne() { } 

    //GET MyData/GetTwo
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetTwo")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetTwo() { }
}
```

Readup on attribute routing here [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: Good point. Project is a upgraded .aspx WebForm application, has Global.asax only, no WebApiConfig.cs or other app_Start files. While trying to add the **MapHttpAttributeRoutes**, it's not available in intellisense. It should be part of System.Web.Http, mine is RunTime Version = v4.0.30319, Version = 5.2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

This is additional answer for legacy app developers like me:

- migrated a huge legacy .aspx WebForm app from VS 08 (.NET 2.x) to VS
  15 (.NET 4.6)
- revive by adding in new technology like API.

After digging around, [this](http://www.zachhunter.com/2015/10/adding-web-api-2-1-to-web-form-app/) is the best found. If you just have Global.asax without .cs, simply add it into .asax.